# Asynchronous Notification with REST

Tags: json, rest, asynchronous, notify

What is the best technique to push notifications from the cloud to a client? REST does not seem to support this. In particular, I have JSON objects representing world state going to the cloud and want to be able to notify a client when that state changes.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to REST.

Answer (score 0):

All HTML5 implementations I've seen support full duplex communication via WebSockets.

If you're using Google App Engine you can use the Channel API.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

If you're using JBoss you can use the Errai Framework.  http://errai.github.io/

I'm sure there are a lot of other options out there.  And there's always email.